# PHP Org Chart image generation

Tags: php

I'm trying to generate an organization chart in PHP; the classic "box" above another "box" connected by lines. I have all the employees in my organization saved in the following database structure...

repots_to_table

- recordId (int)
- staffId (int)
- reports_to (int)
- type (char(1))

Currently, I recursively start at the top (#400 who reports to themself). I don't really care how "wide" the image will be since the idea is I want to generate a final "image" to print or save. Can anyone help me figure out a good way (ideally with built in PHP image libraries) to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: Good, but crashed when I built the "full" tree. Seems to only work at small groups... or probably less than 256 entries